# Rerun an asynchronous method on completion

Tags: c#, xamarin

I intend rerunning an async method continuously under a given condition but can seem to get the logic right:

```
    public void DoWork(Action<bool>callback){
        callback(true);
    }

    public void Test(){
        DoWork((Result) => Console.WriteLine("HERE"));
    }
```

This runs only once.

Ideally when the DoWork method has completed I want it to rerun until a click a button which changes a boolean property status to true. I'm new to c# so how is this normally done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async void TopLevelMethod()
{
    while (!Console.Read().Equals('q'))
    {
       await DoWork();
    }
}

async Task DoWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```